# push_back error for linkedlist

Tags: c++, linked-list

I keep getting the error "no member named push_back in StatePrimary::ListNode." I need help making the changes.

```
void StatePrimary::addCandidate (std::string name, int nVotes)
{
    CandidateInfo info = {name, nVotes, 0};
    stateCandidates-> push_back (info);
}
```

Comment: Do you *have* a member named "push_back" in the class `StatePrimary::ListNode`?

Comment: computer-science tag?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `stateCandidates` is either not a member of `StatePrimary` or is not a `std::vector<CandidateInfo>`.

I'd double check that first.

If I'm wrong please also post the declaration of `stateCandidates`.